# How to send sms from selected contact in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android social networking app. In that I need to send invitation to the contacts in my phone. i.e when i click on invite button it should open contacts from phone and **when a specific contact is selected it should open the send message activity to send default sms**. How can I do that? I was able to open the contacts when invite button is clicked. But how to send sms from my app to a selected contact. Any help in this regard will be really thankful.

Comment: Use **SmsManager** Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SmsManager` class.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

or built-in android sms application.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Note: both need `SEND_SMS` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code on your activity to send sms

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Set below permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```